# Function pointer, how to cast?

Tags: c, casting, function-pointers

I wrote a function to test functions. I want to be flexible, that's the reason for the function pointer.

My code is working, but is there a possibility to avoid the warning below? 
I thought about a cast.

So I tried to set a `(UINT32 *)` in front of the `&tickGet`, but it isn't working.

Can you help me?

```
ULONG tickGet (void);

void WCET_Measurement(UINT32 (*Function)(void)){}

WCET_Measurement(&tickGet);
```

Compiler Warning

```
warning: passing arg 1 of `WCET_Measurement' from incompatible pointer type
```

Comment: why use both ULONG and UINT32? have you tried using one of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cast attempt was wrong.

You need:

```
WCET_Measurement(((UINT32)(*)(void)) tickGet);
```

It's often good to use a `typedef` with function pointers, to make them clearer.

Of course, if the two types `UINT32` and `ULONG` are different on your system, this will break horribly.

Comment: SORRY, don'T know what but It was my fault

Answer (score 3):

Casting function pointers is well-defined.  However, invoking a function through an incompatible pointer is **undefined behaviour**.  So if `UINT32` is a distinct type from a `ULONG`, then things will be wrong.

But if you really want to cast, then you can do this:

```
WCET_Measurement((UINT32 (*)(void))&tickGet);
```

Or better yet, use a `typedef`:

```
typedef UINT32 (*MyFunc)(void);

WCET_Measurement((MyFunc)&tickGet);
```

Comment: @user1829804: Are you sure you copied my example precisely?

Comment: SORRY, don'T know what but It was my fault